# arraylist in constructor java

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

1.If I add an `ArrayList` to my constructor like this in my `Teams` class.

```
public Teams(String teamName, String coachName,ArrayList<Players> playerName ) {
    mTeamName = teamName;
    mCoachName = coachName;
    mPlayersInTeam = playerName;
```

2. I am getting this error in my `Main` class.

`private static Teams teams = new Teams("","");`

getting error here so how to add `ArrayList`?
I did declare the two empty strings as you can see above.

My question is how to I add the `ArrayList` to the argument to get rid of this error?

Comment: `new Teams("","", new ArrayList<Players>())`

Comment: How would you normally create an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Hint: bad naming: your class represents **one** team; not multiple. So why is your class called teamS, instead of "Team"?! On the other hand; you call a list of nameS "playerName". If you think about that ... aint that really confusing? So, you would call that list like "players"? Esp. as that list is of type List of Players. So, the list is not about names, but about objects of the Player class!

Answer (score 0):

It s impossible to add element in ArrayList on that way. Usually, if i need to add elements in List in constructor, i use this solutition:
ClassName instance=new ClassName(**new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(element1,element2,... element2))**,otherArguments);